# C# Webbrowser Element displays HTML Table differently

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, html-table, appearance

I'm displaying a HTML page containing a table in my webbrowser element on a windowsform. However some parts of the table appear differently in the webbrowser element than when I open the HTML file with any browser (including IE).

Here is the comparison:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHzkO.jpg

Top: Any browser ,
Bottom: Webbrowser Element

(In case the link dies someday : some borders appear thicker than they should and vertical text is displayed as horizontal text).

Is there any way to fix this? What might cause this?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of multiple browser with no fixed HTML interpretation! Each browser (even each version) renders HTML differently, if you want to fix those errors then you need to check the browser version and create a different CSS with specific styles for each browser.

Comment: Just looking into similar issues myself, and actively considering replacing the native WebBrowser stuff with http://www.awesomium.com/

Comment: I looked up the CSS code for IE but unfortunately it only supports turning by +90° and not by -90° : *writing-mode: tb-rl has to be used to accomplish this. It looks kind of wierd but works better than not turning at all, at least in my case. I stillt don't know how to fix the borders but that's the smaller problem

Answer (score 1):

The `WebBrowser` control is by default set to emulate IE7, which is probably the cause for this. You can change the IE-Level used for the `WebBrowser` control by creating a registry entry, though it must be set for each individual executable.

For more details (like the exact registry key and possible values) see the following article on Code Project: [Configuring the emulation mode of an Internet Explorer WebBrowser control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793687/Configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-Internet-Expl)